# `fit-window-to-buffer` and `reposition-window` non-interactively

Tags: window

I'm using `lean-mode` and want to keep the *Lean Goals* buffer sized to fit its contents.  Here's what it should look like:

[image]

To get that working, I wrote the following and hooked it in to the relevant function.

```lisp
(defun lean-resize-goal-buffer ()
  (let ((goal-buffer (get-buffer lean-show-goal-buffer-name)))
    (when goal-buffer
      (let ((orig (current-buffer)))
    (pop-to-buffer
     goal-buffer)
    (fit-window-to-buffer nil nil (+ (count-lines (point-min)
                              (point-max))
                     1))
    (pop-to-buffer orig))
    ;; Added this, but it doesn't work as intended
    (reposition-window))))

(advice-add 'lean-show-goal--handler :after #'lean-resize-goal-buffer)
```

The display is a bit jumpy, and I realised I need to run `reposition-window` to get the windows to resize correctly.  But this does not work non-interactively, as in the above function.  When I press <kbd>C-M-l</kbd> it works fine.  Even wrapping `reposition-window` with `call-interactively` doesn't work.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I thought that downloading a newer version of Emacs might fix it but, just checked, it doesn't.

Comment: IIUC when `lean-resize-goal-buffer` is called, the goals buffer is already displayed, so your uses of `pop-to-buffer` are wrong (`pop-to-buffer` is used to *display* a buffer, not to select it).  The first `pop-to-buffer` should be a call to `(with-selected-window (get-buffer-window goal-buffer) ...)` tho you'll likely want to check for corner cases where `get-buffer-window` might return nil (in which case there's no window to resize).  The second call to `pop-to-buffer` can then disappear (the corresponding operation is performed by `with-selected-window` at the end).

Comment: Hi @Stefan Thanks, I made that alteration, but unfortunately it doesn't address the key annoyance that `reposition-window` doesn't behave the same way when called non-interactively.